# Java Mappings and Primitives

Tags: java, dictionary, primitive, word-wrap

I want to create a mapping that takes a `String` as the key and a *primitive* as the value. I was looking at the Java docs and did not see that Primitive was a class type, or that they shared some kind of wrapping class.

How can I constrain the value to be a primitive?

`Map<String, Primitive> map = new HashMap<String, Primitive>();`

Comment: It was my fault for being unclear. What I say I want to constrain the value to being a primitive type I mean that I want the to allow any of the primitive types to be used as a value in that specific map.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Java Autoboxing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html) allows to create maps on `Long, Integer, Double` and then operate them using primitive values. For example:

```
java.util.HashMap<String, Integer> map = new java.util.HashMap<String, Integer>();
map.put("one", 1); // 1 is an integer, not an instance of Integer
```

If you want to store in one map different primitive types, you can to it by making a `Map<String, Number>`. Allows to store values of `BigDecimal`, `BigInteger`, `Byte`, `Double`, `Float`, `Integer`, `Long`, `Short` (and `AtomicLong`, `AtomicInteger`).

Here is an example:

```
Map<String, Number> map = new HashMap<String, Number>();

map.put("one", 1);
map.put("two", 2.0);
map.put("three", 1L);

for(String k:map.keySet()) {
  Number v = map.get(k);
  System.err.println(v + " is instance of " + v.getClass().getName() + ": " + v);
}
```

Comment: Is there a way with generics to specify an or clause? Say for instance < String , Boat | Car>

Comment: @Doodle you should make a base class `Vehicle` and extend it in `Boat, Car` and then make `<String, Vehicle>`.

Comment: Yes, extract a supertype Vehicle and make it a Map<String, Vehicle> or Map<String, ? extends Vehicle> (the Generics syntax always confuses me)

Comment: I was considering strings being a value that could be useful to pass    < String , Number | Strings>

Comment: Haha, we had the same idea khachik, but you can type faster ;)

Comment: There's a supertype of Number and Strings. It's called Object!

Comment: Haha Very True ! I am seeing that the problem with my logic is that you won`t know what type the returned object from the map will be with out testing it then.

Answer (score 4):

Google for "Java Primitive Maps" and you will find some specialised types which avoid the need for autoboxing. An example of this is: https://labs.carrotsearch.com/hppc.html

However, in general you should do fine with autoboxing as mentioned in other answers.

Comment: Thats a bump for showing me Fast util thats something that may be usefull to me thank you.

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: I've replace the dead link with a working up to date one

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>()
```

Then operations like:

```
map.put("One", 1);
```

will work.  The primitive `1` will get auto-boxed into an `Integer`.  Likewise:

```
int i = map.get("One");
```

will also work because the `Integer` will get auto-unboxed into an `int`.

Check out some documentation on [autoboxing and autounboxing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html).

Answer (score 2):

Every primitive has a wrapper class, like [`java.lang.Long`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html) for `long`.

So you can map the the wrapper class to `String`and, if you use Java 1.5+, simply put primitives to the map:

```
 Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
 map.put("key", 10);
 int value = map.get("key");  // value is 10.
```

Answer (score 1):

You would use their boxed counterpart.

```
Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
```

Integer is an immutable boxed type of the primitive int.  There are similar Short, Long, Double, Float and Byte boxed types.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the value to be a primitive for performance reasons, you can use [TObjectIntHashMap](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/TObjectIntHashMap.html) or similar.

e.g.

```
TObjectIntHashMap<String> map = new TObjectIntHashMap();

map.put("key", 10);
int value = map.get("key");
```

One difference with Map<String, Integer> is that the values are of type int primitive rather than Integer object.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a primitive as key or value in `Map` interface. Instead you can use Wrapper classes, like `Integer`, `Character`, `Boolean` and so on.

Read more on [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_wrapper_class).

Comment: Autoboxing should take care of that if java 1.5 onwards is used so you don't need to wrap the primitives manually