# How can I store primitive types in Hashmap or list as a value instead of a wrapper class object

Tags: java

The question had been asked to me in an interview.

I know that primitive types will be converted into wrapper class object to store in any data structure.

But interviewer asked me I dont want it to be a wrapper class object and it should be stored as primitive type.

How can we do that?

Comment: No data structure List,Set,Map store primitives. for your answer you can create array of primitive type as array is also data structure and then you can put that array to list,set or map what ever your choice.

Comment: for future reference, this is usually done with library: http://trove.starlight-systems.com/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using Java's Collection API, you cannot do it in a sensible way. Of course you could implement the `List` or `Map` interfaces yourself and decide to store primitives instead of objects but that would cause you a headache anyway. Java's collection interfaces are all based on objects (Generics don't even play a role in that), so you cannot have an `add` or `remove` method that takes an int as its argument.

Let's say you have your own implementation of `List<Integer>` that stores `int`instead of the `Integer` defined by the interface, you could write something like this:

```
List<Integer> intList = new MyPrimitiveImplementation<>();
intList.add(42);
```

Now what happens is that the primitive int 42 gets autoboxed to an `Integer` object because the `Collection` interface defines the add method as `add(Integer e)`. What your implementation could then do would be unboxing the `Integer` object again just to get the primitive back.

So, there's really no point. You either get serious performance trouble (imagine the above autoboxing happening a couple million times), or you lose compatibility with the Collections API. Both are undesirable.

Comment: There is one point to it. You could write additional methods such as `addInt(int a)` and `int getInt(int index)` methods which deal directly with the `int`s as they are stored and don't involve any boxing or unboxing at all. That way you could use the `List` in a very efficient way and yet also have the benefits of the `List<Integer>` interface when you actually need it. My view is that they should have done something like that with android's `SparseArray`, but few people seem to agree with me.

Comment: @pbabcdefp: With Java 8, I would expect the performance of a `HashMap` to be on par with such a `SparseArray` for most use cases.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement the interfaces `List`, `Set` and `Map` however you like. Therefore it would be perfectly possible to write an implementation of `List<Integer>`, for example, where all the items are stored internally as primitive `int` values. However, if you use the most common implementations of these interfaces (`ArrayList`, `HashSet` and `HashMap`) all of the values will be stored internally as `Objects` (which include boxed primitives like `Integer` as well as array types like `int[]`.

Comment: He asks to use a primitive type, Integer isn't

Comment: I know it isn't. If the question is can you have a `List<T>` where `T` is a primitive type like `int`, the answer is no. However, just because you have to have a `List<Integer>` rather than a `List<int>` doesn't mean the items have to be stored internally as boxed primitives.

Answer (score 0):

You can put it in an array of the primitive type.

For an int value,

```
List<int[]> list = new ArrayList<int[]>()
```

Then put it with

```
list.add(new int[]{value});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414920/why-primitive-datatypes-are-not-allowd-in-java-util-arraylist

Comment: That is still a wrapper

Comment: No wrapper as you see

Comment: The arrays would be a kind of wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Java containers store Objects, not primitives, period. You can check the Collections interface [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html), and see that it's based on generics:

> java.util Interface Collection
>
> Type Parameters: E - the type of elements in this collection All
>
> Superinterfaces: Iterable All Known Subinterfaces: BeanContext,
> BeanContextServices, BlockingDeque, BlockingQueue, Deque,
> **List**, NavigableSet, Queue, **Set**, SortedSet,
> TransferQueue

And by definition, generics are replaced by objects, not primitives. from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java):

> Note that you cannot use primitive types, ex:

```
Entry<int, int> pair; // this fails. You have to use Integer instead.
```

So, concluding, you can write your own list or map implementation, but never implement any of the existing generic interfaces that are based on Collection.

You can find more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13216314/hashmap-does-not-work-with-int-char), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504959/why-can-java-collections-not-directly-store-primitives-types) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4399645/java-mappings-and-primitives)

Answer (score -1):

You cannot store primitive types in any java.util collection. To do what you want maybe the easiest way is to do a composition like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class IntList  {

ArrayList<Integer> myList;

public void add(int i){
    myList.add(new Integer(i));
}

// rest of methods...
}
```